# Xamarin remote build port add-on

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Im currently thinking about developing iOS App with Xamarin and Visual Studio via a macincloud remote desktop. 
I have read a number of different articles on this topic and I came to this one [Xamarin iOS apps in Visual Studio and Macincloud](https://birdsbits.wordpress.com/2015/12/05/developing-ios-apps-in-visual-studio-with-macincloud/)

It states that you have to get a "Xamarin remote build port add-on". I just want to know exactly what is this and how to obtain one of these?

I look forward to any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Macincloud needs to open a port on the firewall on your rental Mac so Xamarin can connect to it... Like the blog post says, contact Macincloud's support.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: how do you get a test iOS device to connect from your local machine to the build agent?

Answer (score 1):

Basically it opens the Xamarin remote build port. If you don't add it, the connection from Visual Studio will be rejected by the MacinCloud Mac. You can ask the support to add it if you do not have it yet.